# Data structures for 3D Tables Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have many tables with the same format. I wish to put them together as a 3D Table like a nested Table

Example
Table1 denoted as 201601
Within Table 1,

```
Names Prices
AAPL  10
IBM   20
```

Table2 denoted as 201602
Within Table 2,

```
Names Prices
AAPL  11
IBM   21
```

You may ask me why not put under same Table with Date, Names and Prices. This is because each table, I want to run some analysis like regression and if one date is wrong, I can easily replace that table instead of messing up one single large Table.

Desired output will be like 3D Table

201601, 201602, 201603 ...

Each table ie 201601 will contain a Table of ie Names and Prices.

Do you know how to build a nested Tables?

Thank you

Comment: Put your tables in a cell, `all_table = {table1,table2,...}`, then access the first table with `all_table{1}`, the second with `all_table{2}`...

Comment: I need to label each table according to the date ie 201001 201002. If I use your method, I could not pull the table according to the date.

Comment: Also, is it easier/efficient to put tables in a cell array as you suggested like 4000 tables, each with 3000 rows or combine them in one giant table with 12 Million rows? I would need to pull the data according to the date to compute.